# What the list of possible resolutions in Display settings depends on?

Tags: resolution

What the list of possible resolutions depends on?

I have the following list of resolutions in Display settings:

[image]

Actual monitor resolution is 1280x1024 i.e. not listed.

How to make this list correct?

OS is Ubuntu 12.04 inside Oracle VM.

P.S. I need not force my system to be 1280x1024, I need to fix resolutions list.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer whether you can increase your screen resolution depends on the size and capability of your monitor and the type of video card you have, and your computer's configuration.

Comment: Screen and video card are definitely capable of desired resolution. Only Ubuntu does not know this. How to teach it?

Comment: What is the amount of memory used under the display settings in VB?  And did you install guest editions?

Comment: It is 12 Mb. But this can't limit the list since 1600x1200 is greater than 1280x1024 but still listed.

Comment: What is the host OS?  Have you tried changing the res. there?

Comment: Host OS is Windows and it shows 1280x1024 which is native for this LCD display.